# Largest item always displays first in Isotope

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

I have been experimenting with the excellent jQuery Isotope library, and I have a working example here: http://nmcweb.co.uk/crv

What I want is every time an item is clicked on and expands, it moves to the top left of the grid, essentially becoming the first item in the sort order. I've tried the code from several similar questions on stack overflow but with no luck.

It tends to work for the first few clicks, but after that it stops. Any ideas?

I'm new to jQuery, so I may have missed something really dumb.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

 <div class="box">
    <a href="#"><img src="./stock/1.png" /></a>
      <div class="more" >
         <p>Text blah blah blah</p>

      </div>
   </div>
```

jQuery:

```
            <script>$(window).load(function(){


  var $container = $('#container');

  $container.isotope({
     masonry: {
      columnWidth: 320
    },

    itemSelector: '.box',

    getSortData : {
      width : function( $item ){
        // sort by biggest width first, then by original order
        return -$item.width() + $item.index();
      }
    },
    sortBy : 'width'

  })

     $('.box').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        tileStyle = $this.hasClass('big') ? { width: 300 } : { width: 620 };

    $this.addClass('big').children('.more').show();
    $this.siblings().removeClass('big').children('.more').hide();


    $container.isotope( 'updateSortData', $this ).isotope();

  });


});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rework of a fiddle (can't find link :(
The original had links on the tiles that gave what I imagine is exactly what you are after. I will look about my local system a bit more but... ah, the muddle. I hope this helps.

```
<style>
.element {  width: 75px;  height: 75px;  background: #0FF;  margin: 5px;  float: left;}
.trans { width: 75px;  height: 75px;  background: #F0F;  margin: 5px; float:left}
.element.searchPali {  width: 160px;  height: 160px;  background: red;}
/* Start: Recommended Isotope styles *//**** Isotope Filtering ****/
.isotope-item {  z-index: 2;}
.isotope-hidden.isotope-item {  pointer-events: none;  z-index: 1;}
/**** Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
.isotope,.isotope .isotope-item {  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;     -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;          transition-duration: 0.8s;}
.isotope {  -webkit-transition-property: height, width;     -moz-transition-property: height, width;          transition-property: height, width;}
.isotope .isotope-item {  -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform, opacity;     -moz-transition-property:    -moz-transform, opacity;          transition-property:         transform, opacity;}
/**** disabling Isotope CSS3 transitions ****/
.isotope.no-transition,.isotope.no-transition .isotope-item,.isotope .isotope-item.no-transition {  -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;     -moz-transition-duration: 0s;          transition-duration: 0s;}
/* End: Recommended Isotope styles */
</style>

<table border=1><TR><TD>
<div class="trans">One <a href="#" id="tile-4">link to element D</a></div>
<div class="trans">Two<a href="#" id="tile-3">link to element C</a></div>
</TD><TD>
<div class="trans">Three <a href="#" id="tile-6">link to element F</a></div>
<div class="trans">Four<a href="#" id="tile-7">link to element G</a></div>
</TD></TR></table>

<div id="container" style='width:355px;border:1px solid black'>
<table ><TR><TD>
<div id="1" class="element">A</div>
<div id="2" class="element">B</div>
<div id="3" class="element">C</div>
<div id="4" class="element">D</div>

</TD><TD valign=top>
<div id="5" class="element">E</div>
<div id="6" class="element">F</div>
<div id="7" class="element">G</div>
</TD></TR></table>
</div>
<script src="../../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

var $container = $('#container'),
$items = $('a');
$container.isotope({ itemSelector: '.element',
masonry: { columnWidth: 85 },
getSortData: { 
searchPali: function($item) { return ($item.hasClass('searchPali') ? -1000 : 0) + $item.index(); }
},
sortBy: 'searchPali'
});

$('.trans').click(function(event) {
var $targetID = event.target.id;
$targetID =  $targetID.replace('tile-','');
$this=$('#'+$targetID);
var $previoussearch = $('.searchPali');
if (!$this.hasClass('searchPali')) { $this.addClass('searchPali'); }
$previoussearch.removeClass('searchPali');
$container.isotope('updateSortData', $this).isotope('updateSortData', $previoussearch).isotope();
});

});
</script>
```